# Rest Assured post request with cookie and content type Text/plain

Tags: java, rest, http-post, rest-assured

I'm using rest assured to test API's.am facing issues in making a request with below configuration using rest assured.

Request type : **POST**

**Headers:**

Content-Type :text/plain

api-key : 12263783493

user : emailid

Cookie : changesetId=4604

**Body type-:  raw : Text**

**applyToAllMapsOnController=false&applyToAllMaps=false**  (this is the text in the request body to be passed)

Below is what I tried but I'm getting 400 bad request

```
Response response=  (Response) RestAssured.given().

header("Content-Type", "text/plain").
header("charset","utf-8").
header("api-key","dV43+Rbr9uncPd&;ydiQx]uUFX2").
header("user","P2899445,Bhavan Ramakrishnappa").
cookie("cookie", "changesetId="+Number).
body("applyToAllMapsOnController=false&applyToAllMaps=false").
  when().
  post(servicelevel);
```

Can someone help me how to pass cookie in header and raw text in the body?

Comment: Can someone help with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple things to Debug the issue.

1. Try passing ("cookie", "changesetId="+Number) as a header
2. use when().log().all so that you can see what is the Request being Sent.

Comment: Thanks Arun , this helped to debug and fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you left them out on purpose, but I don't see here a baseURI or path given.
Other than that, header for Content-Type and body seems properly set.